# Accessing a struct within a function using it's struct pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, tree

I am trying to create a tri-nary tree in C++, It reads a file and creates the tree based on the words it reads. Each node has a character, and then a list of all the words in the file that started with that character, a parent pointer, a left1 pointer, a left2 pointer, and a right pointer.

In my program I have the struct:

```
   struct node_t{
   node_t *parent;
      node_t *left1;
      node_t *left2;
      node_t *right;
      char letter;
      vector<string> wordList;
      int lineCount;
  };
```

and I have the prototype to insert a word

```
int insertWord(ifstream &dataFile, node_t *parent, char myLetter);
```

Then in Main I call a function insertWord

```
if (insertWord(dataFile, &root, ch) == 0{
     //if no errors occurred in function do something
}
```

Then in insertWord I try to add words to my parent node's vector Array if the word belongs in the parent array:

```
parent->wordList.push_back(word);
```

When I try to print out the list back in main, it has not added the word to the list. When I print it out in insertWord, it does have the word added to the list.
I know it's a pointer problem, but I just can't see what I'm doing wrong. I didn't post all my code because there is so much of it.

Any ideas on how to successfully add my word to the list so it prints out in main?

Comment: You are accessing it correctly. You're probably trying to print from the wrong object, or the parent doesn't point at the object you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly you don't provide us enough information. What you are doing is overall correct but what about details ? I think you defined `root` as a `node_t`, ie.:

```
node_t root;
```

Meaning that the root is the first node. Then you pass `&root` and `insertWord` receives it as `node_t *parent`. However, `insertWord` has to detect and deal with the empty root (how is it encoded btw) and will do something like:

```
parent = some newly allocated node
```

but doing this has no effect on the `root` variable (which is passed by value actually).

So you need to declare:

```
node_t *root;
```

and continue to pass `&root`. In `insertWord` you receive a `node_t **pparent` (pointer to the parent) so you can modify the parent (ie. the root). In `insertWord`, replace all `parent` by `*pparent`, e.g.

```
*pparent = some newly allocated node
```

I suppose the `insertWord` function is recursive and you should have code like:

```
insertWord(...,parent->left1,...)
```

which becomes

```
insertWord(...,&(*pparent->left1),...)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Sorry for the lack of information. I was not passing the value right, so I changed my root to *root and did what you said and it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you probably pass by value somewhere and you want pass by reference or pointer. I don't see the problem in this code but go in the debugger and make sure the address of the struct and the pointer value match from main down to insertWord